# JavaScript slidedown without jQuery

Tags: javascript

I wish to have a similar effect to jQuery slidedown but **without** using jQuery or any other libary. I know it's "possible" as anything in jQuery can be done in plain JavaScript. Just harder.

I cannot use jQuery as everything has to be written in my own code without any libaries used.

Has anyone done something like this or any effects just using plain JavaScript?

Comment: I think it can be done with the combination of these: javascript setInterval(), css height, and css overflow=hidden;

Comment: Pretty much what LatinSuD said. It's not difficult, it's just boring to reinvent the wheel. I don't see why you aren't allowed to use "any libraries".

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here is a nice little piece of code I wrote from scratch.
It is purely **time based**.

```
var minheight = 20;
var maxheight = 100;
var time = 1000;
var timer = null;
var toggled = false;

window.onload = function() {
    var controller = document.getElementById('slide');
    var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
    slider.style.height = minheight + 'px'; //not so imp,just for my example
    controller.onclick = function() {  
        clearInterval(timer);
        var instanceheight = parseInt(slider.style.height);  // Current height
        var init = (new Date()).getTime(); //start time
        var height = (toggled = !toggled) ? maxheight: minheight; //if toggled

        var disp = height - parseInt(slider.style.height);
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            var instance = (new Date()).getTime() - init; //animating time
            if(instance <= time ) { //0 -> time seconds
                var pos = instanceheight + Math.floor(disp * instance / time);
                slider.style.height =  pos + 'px';
            }else {
                slider.style.height = height + 'px'; //safety side ^^
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        },1);
    };
};
```

Test it here: **http://jsbin.com/azewi5/5**

Comment: Thanks is it possible to have it working when the div is hidden in css and then its shown as it slides down?

Comment: yes, I believe It can be done by adding few more lines of code will do the job

Comment: @elliott try the updated demo http://jsbin.com/azewi5/3 , I'm using opacity to vary the visibility

Comment: Setting timeout to 1ms is not recommended because OSes other than Windows usually have the kernel tick set higher than that (Linux and BSD set it to 10ms I believe which would make 10ms the minimum recommended value). This will have the effect that on other OSes the animation will appear slow compared to Windows.

Comment: Besides, 1000 frames per second is a very optimistic target. Even Quake doesn't try to reach that goal :-P

Comment: Using css is better than hacking js for transition effect (YES - using setInterval or setTimeout is a hack). Check out my solution.

Comment: From the future, I'd recommend using an interval of 17, because 17/1000 is about 1/60, and 60fps is a realistic goal for framerate. Using 1000fps is just a waste of processing power.

Answer (score 62):

Since we are in 2014, why not use CSS transitions and just change the height property of the element?
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qnas3zog/4/)

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    transition:height 1s ease-out;
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
//content
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
document.getElementById("wrapper").style.height = //content height +"px";
```

## 2020 EDIT (dealing with unknown height):

So we're in 2020 and it's even more obvious now we should rely on CSS effects for this kind of animations.

However, a valid point has been made against this answer - you need to specify the height of the element that you're animating in the js code, and you might not know this value in advance.

So six years later, I'm adding a couple extra lines of code to cover this case.

So if we use the same CSS and HTML as in our old 2014 example, this is the new JS. 
[New Fiddle!](https://jsfiddle.net/hzqj6wps/)

```
const slideDown = elem => elem.style.height = `${elem.scrollHeight}px`;

slideDown(document.getElementById("wrapper"));
```

Comment: Browser compatibility is the reason to do it, even in 2014, and if people don't know how to do it the browser-compatible way (pure JS or jQuery), then it poses issues in their abilities as a frontend developer. Too many developers take the CSS3 approach, which is an issue for a large segment of the population on browsers with little to no CSS3 support.

Comment: @ScriptsConnect There is something called graceful degradation, and this is a perfect example for this. The user will still see the height change, only that not animated.  And that only happends for the very small segment of the population who use IE9-.

Comment: I'm aware of what graceful degradation is. But we're now off the topic of the point of the OP, which was that the user wanted to know about a JavaScript solution and not a jQuery solution.

Comment: @ScriptsConnect I don't fully agree. Yes, the OP asked for a javascript solution, but bear in mind that in 2010 CSS transitions were uncharted territory as they didn't have solid cross-browser support. This solution is an elegant one with minimal JS & CSS.

Comment: One problem is if you don't know the content height (which is not a niche use case)

Comment: If you don't know the content height, you can display the content first, and get the height of it (via [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)), then hide it immediately (So user won't see it), now you have the height of the content.

Comment: its 2018 and this should be the top answer. https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions

Comment: This solution doesnt work for me, Win10 Chrome 70, if I change height property from '0px' to 'initial'. Only works for numeric values: px, em, rem etc. So it's pretty useless, if you don't have elements initial height (which is quite hard to find with pure JS)

Answer (score 28):

As an improvement to @Ruben Serrate solution which misses the use case for unknown height,
I've created this using CSS3 and javascript (no jQuery):

```
/**
* getHeight - for elements with display:none
 */
getHeight = function(el) {
    var el_style      = window.getComputedStyle(el),
        el_display    = el_style.display,
        el_position   = el_style.position,
        el_visibility = el_style.visibility,
        el_max_height = el_style.maxHeight.replace('px', '').replace('%', ''),

        wanted_height = 0;


    // if its not hidden we just return normal height
    if(el_display !== 'none' && el_max_height !== '0') {
        return el.offsetHeight;
    }

    // the element is hidden so:
    // making the el block so we can meassure its height but still be hidden
    el.style.position   = 'absolute';
    el.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    el.style.display    = 'block';

    wanted_height     = el.offsetHeight;

    // reverting to the original values
    el.style.display    = el_display;
    el.style.position   = el_position;
    el.style.visibility = el_visibility;

    return wanted_height;
};


/**
* toggleSlide mimics the jQuery version of slideDown and slideUp
* all in one function comparing the max-heigth to 0
 */
toggleSlide = function(el) {
    var el_max_height = 0;

    if(el.getAttribute('data-max-height')) {
        // we've already used this before, so everything is setup
        if(el.style.maxHeight.replace('px', '').replace('%', '') === '0') {
            el.style.maxHeight = el.getAttribute('data-max-height');
        } else {
            el.style.maxHeight = '0';
        }
    } else {
        el_max_height                  = getHeight(el) + 'px';
        el.style['transition']         = 'max-height 0.5s ease-in-out';
        el.style.overflowY             = 'hidden';
        el.style.maxHeight             = '0';
        el.setAttribute('data-max-height', el_max_height);
        el.style.display               = 'block';

        // we use setTimeout to modify maxHeight later than display (to we have the transition effect)
        setTimeout(function() {
            el.style.maxHeight = el_max_height;
        }, 10);
    }
}
```

Here is the demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/pgfk2mvo/

Please let me know if you can find any improvements to this as I always try to improve my code. Happy coding ! :D

Comment: works great, but has problems when something starts open.

Comment: @StevenWade What do you mean with _something starts open_? Does something interfere with the animation? In what case? Make an edit to the JSFiddle perhaps?

Comment: This "toggle" will have a visual bug if the div to be slided down is visible initially.

Answer (score 16):

Here's the solution to use slideDown, slideUp animation with an **unknown content height** element. https://jsfiddle.net/gebpjo1L/18/

It based on the CSS 3 height animation, but the animation requires a specified content height, so you need to get the height of the content via JavaScript before you expanding it.

```js
var container = document.querySelector('div')
var button    = document.querySelector('button')

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    /** Slide down. */
    if(!container.classList.contains('active')) {
        /** Show the container. */
     container.classList.add('active')
        container.style.height = "auto"
        
        /** Get the computed height of the container. */
     var height = container.clientHeight + "px"

        /** Set the height of the content as 0px, */
        /** so we can trigger the slide down animation. */
        container.style.height = "0px"

        /** Do this after the 0px has applied. */
        /** It's like a delay or something. MAGIC! */
        setTimeout(() => {
            container.style.height = height
        }, 0) 
    
 /** Slide up. */
    } else {
     /** Set the height as 0px to trigger the slide up animation. */
     container.style.height = "0px"
        
        /** Remove the `active` class when the animation ends. */
     container.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
         container.classList.remove('active')
        }, {once: true})
    }
})
```

```css
div {
    transition: height .5s ease;
    overflow  : hidden;
}

div:not(.active) {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
    I'm an unknown content height element. 
    I'm an unknown content height element. 
    I'm an unknown content height element. 
    I'm an unknown content height element. 
    I'm an unknown content height element. 
    I'm an unknown content height element. 
    I'm an unknown content height element. 
    I'm an unknown content height element. 
    I'm an unknown content height element. 
    I'm an unknown content height element. 
    I'm an unknown content height element. 
    I'm an unknown content height element. 
</div>
<button>Slide Toggle</button>
```

Comment: Any reason to use `window.getComputedStyle(container, null).getPropertyValue("height")`  instead of `container.clientHeight` ?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know `container.clientHeight` does exist. I think they both do the same thing but `container.clientHeight` is faster so I edited the answer, thank you.

Comment: This one is the best solution I've found so far. Small and concise and using CSS transitions.

Comment: This works for me, but I can't understand one thing. Why don't we have a flickering when you do `container.style.height = "auto"` (to calculate height) and then go back to 0px ? Shouldn't we see something or it happens just too fast to appear on screen ?

Comment: I think it's too fast to appear on the screen

Answer (score 15):

> > can be done in plain JavaScript. Just harder.

Actually it's not too hard. You just need to get comfortable with `setTimeout()` (which is a good idea anyway since it teaches you the programming style of node.js). The most bare-bones implementation (does not have all of jQuery's features, that's left as homework for the reader):

```
function slideDown (element, duration, finalheight, callback) {
    var s = element.style;
    s.height = '0px';

    var y = 0;
    var framerate = 10;
    var one_second = 1000;
    var interval = one_second*duration/framerate;
    var totalframes = one_second*duration/interval;
    var heightincrement = finalheight/totalframes;
    var tween = function () {
        y += heightincrement;
        s.height = y+'px';
        if (y<finalheight) {
            setTimeout(tween,interval);
        }
    }
    tween();
}
```

Of course, that's not the shortest possible way to write it and you don't have to declare all those variables like `one_second` etc. I just did it this way for clarity to show what's going on.

This example is also shorter and easier to understand than trying to read jQuery's source code.

---

> > Has anyone done something like this or any effects just using plain JavaScript?

Oh yeah, sure, it's the sort of thing I do for fun on weekends:

- http://slebetman.110mb.com/tank3.html (hint: units are clickable)
- http://slebetman.110mb.com/jsgames/freakout

Answer (score 4):

The problem with the earlier answers is you need to know the height before you start. Many times you do not. I built a slid down the you first build a holder div, put the object to ge the slide down inside set the display of the object to block and get the height and use this for the sind. When the side is finished the holder is rmoved do the slide down when done remove it. below is the example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div >
            <div id="test" style="height: 150px; width: 100px; background-color: yellowgreen; display:none">block</div>
        </div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div onclick="slideUp(document.getElementById('test'));">slide Up</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div onclick="slideDown(document.getElementById('test'))">slide down</div>
        <script>
            function slideDown(obj, speed) {
                var mySpeed = speed || 300;
                var intervals = mySpeed / 30; // we are using 30 ms intervals
                alert('intervals = ' + intervals);
                var holder = document.createElement('div');//
                var parent = obj.parentNode;
                holder.setAttribute('style', 'height: 0px; overflow:hidden');
                parent.insertBefore(holder, obj);
                parent.removeChild(obj);
                holder.appendChild(obj);
                obj.style.display = obj.getAttribute("data-original-display") || "";
                var height = obj.offsetHeight;
                var sepHeight = height / intervals;
                //  alert(sepHeight)
                var timer = setInterval(function() {
                    var holderHeight = holder.offsetHeight;
                    if (holderHeight + sepHeight < height) {
                        holder.style.height = (holderHeight + sepHeight) + 'px';
                    } else {
                        // clean up
                        holder.removeChild(obj);
                        parent.insertBefore(obj, holder);
                        parent.removeChild(holder);
                        clearInterval(timer);
                    }
                }, 30);
            }

            function slideUp(obj, speed) {
                var mySpeed = speed || 300;
                var intervals = mySpeed / 30; // we are using 30 ms intervals
                var height = obj.offsetHeight;
                var holder = document.createElement('div');//
                var parent = obj.parentNode;
                holder.setAttribute('style', 'height: ' + height + 'px; overflow:hidden');
                parent.insertBefore(holder, obj);
                parent.removeChild(obj);
                holder.appendChild(obj);
                var originalDisplay = (obj.style.display !== 'none') ? obj.style.display : '';
                obj.setAttribute("data-original-display", originalDisplay);
                var sepHeight = height / intervals;
                //  alert(sepHeight)
                var timer = setInterval(function() {
                    var holderHeight = holder.offsetHeight;
                    console.log(holderHeight);
                    if (holderHeight - sepHeight > 0) {
                        holder.style.height = (holderHeight - sepHeight) + 'px';
                    } else {
                        // clean up
                        obj.style.display = 'none';
                        holder.removeChild(obj);
                        parent.insertBefore(obj, holder);
                        parent.removeChild(holder);
                        clearInterval(timer);
                    }
                }
                , 30);
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `slideUp` function works fine but `slideDown` function seems to be missing display part of element.

Answer (score 3):

After tinkering a little with [Symba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29047447/2787953) I came up with this to take into account padding and borders:

```
toggleSlide = function (el) {
    var el_max_height = 0;
    if (el.getAttribute('data-max-height')) {
        if (el.style.maxHeight.replace('px', '').replace('%', '') === '0') {
            el.style.maxHeight = el.getAttribute('data-max-height');
            el.style.paddingTop = el.getAttribute('data-pad-top');
            el.style.paddingBottom = el.getAttribute('data-pad-bottom');
            el.style.borderTop = el.getAttribute('data-border-top');
            el.style.borderBottom = el.getAttribute('data-border-bottom');
        } else {
            el.style.maxHeight = '0';
            el.style.paddingTop = '0';
            el.style.paddingBottom = '0';
            el.style.borderBottom = '0';
            el.style.borderTop = '0';
        }
    } else {
        el_max_height = getHeight(el) + 'px';
        el.style['transition-property'] = 'max-height, padding-top, padding-bottom, border-bottom, border-top';
        el.style['transition-duration'] = '0.5s';
        el.style['transition-timing-function'] = 'ease-in-out';
        el.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
        el.style.maxHeight = '0';
        el.setAttribute('data-max-height', el_max_height);
        el.setAttribute('data-pad-top', el.style.paddingTop);
        el.setAttribute('data-pad-bottom', el.style.paddingBottom);
        el.setAttribute('data-border-top', el.style.borderTop);
        el.setAttribute('data-border-bottom', el.style.borderBottom);
        el.style.display = 'block';
        setTimeout(function () { el.style.maxHeight = el_max_height; }, 10);
    }
}
```

There's a bit of flicker at top border when expanding transition begins and I don't know (yet) how to fix that.

I didn't modify Symba's getHeight function; for that see his answer.

Answer (score 3):

this pure js solution doesn't require knowing the the max-height beforehand, and uses css-transitions.

it will set max-height to 2x browser window's height during transition, and then the remove max-height after the transition is done.

full slideDown, slideUp demo @
https://kaizhu256.github.io/node-swagger-lite/build..alpha..travis-ci.org/app/index.html

css

```
.swggAnimateSlide {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition: all 500ms linear;
}
.swggAnimateSlideUp {
    border-bottom: 0 !important;
    border-top: 0 !important;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    max-height: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    padding-top: 0 !important;
}
```

js

```
domAnimateSlideDown = function (element) {
/*
 * this function will slideDown the dom-element
 */
    if (element.style.maxHeight || element.style.display !== 'none') {
        return;
    }
    element.classList.add('swggAnimateSlideUp');
    element.classList.add('swggAnimateSlide');
    element.style.display = '';
    setTimeout(function () {
        element.style.maxHeight = 2 * window.innerHeight + 'px';
        element.classList.remove('swggAnimateSlideUp');
    }, 50);
    setTimeout(function () {
        element.style.maxHeight = '';
        element.classList.remove('swggAnimateSlide');
    }, 500);
};


domAnimateSlideUp = function (element) {
/*
 * this function will slideUp the dom-element
 */
    if (element.style.maxHeight || element.style.display === 'none') {
        return;
    }
    element.style.maxHeight = 2 * window.innerHeight + 'px';
    element.classList.add('swggAnimateSlide');
    setTimeout(function () {
        element.classList.add('swggAnimateSlideUp');
        element.style.maxHeight = '0px';
    }, 50);
    setTimeout(function () {
        element.style.display = 'none';
        element.style.maxHeight = '';
        element.classList.remove('swggAnimateSlide');
        element.classList.remove('swggAnimateSlideUp');
    }, 500);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I spent a lot of time to develop these functions and make them the most similar to JQuery's ones, I think they are some details to be optimized in the morph function mainly on length

```js
function morph( element, options, animationTime, callback ) { 
// options is an array with the same structural of Properties and DiffValues and which contains the properties values we want the animation make
 var ComputedElementStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element,null);
 var AttrElementStyle = element.style;
 var Properties = { // the actuals computed properties
  width:   parseInt( ComputedElementStyle.getPropertyValue("width")),
  height:  parseInt( ComputedElementStyle.getPropertyValue("height")),
  padding: {
   top:  parseInt(ComputedElementStyle.getPropertyValue("padding-top")),
   right:  parseInt(ComputedElementStyle.getPropertyValue("padding-right")),
   bot:  parseInt(ComputedElementStyle.getPropertyValue("padding-bottom")),
   left: parseInt(ComputedElementStyle.getPropertyValue("padding-left"))
   },
  margin:{
   top:  parseInt(ComputedElementStyle.getPropertyValue("margin-top")),
   right:  parseInt(ComputedElementStyle.getPropertyValue("margin-right")),
   bot:  parseInt(ComputedElementStyle.getPropertyValue("margin-bottom")),
   left: parseInt(ComputedElementStyle.getPropertyValue("margin-left"))
   } 
 };
 var DiffValues = { // the differences between actual properties values and values we want to
  width:  (options['width']!=null) ? (options['width'] - Properties['width']) : 0,
  height:  (options['height']!=null) ? (options['height'] - Properties['height']) : 0,
  padding: {
   top:  (options['padding']&&options['padding']['top']!=null) ? options['padding']['top'] - Properties['padding']['top'] : 0,
   right:  (options['padding']&&options['padding']['right']!=null) ? options['padding']['right'] - Properties['padding']['right'] : 0,
   bot:  (options['padding']&&options['padding']['bot']!=null) ? options['padding']['bot'] - Properties['padding']['bot'] : 0,
   left:  (options['padding']&&options['padding']['left']!=null) ? options['padding']['left'] - Properties['padding']['left'] : 0
   },
  margin:{
   top:  (options['margin']&&options['margin']['top']!=null) ? options['margin']['top'] - Properties['margin']['top'] : 0,
   right:  (options['margin']&&options['margin']['right']!=null) ? options['margin']['right'] - Properties['margin']['right'] : 0,
   bot:  (options['margin']&&options['margin']['bot']!=null) ? options['margin']['bot'] - Properties['margin']['bot'] : 0,
   left:  (options['margin']&&options['margin']['left']!=null) ? options['margin']['left'] - Properties['margin']['left'] : 0
   }
 };
 var beginTime = new Date().getTime(); // time at begining of animation
 animationTime = (animationTime!=null) ? animationTime : 250;
 AttrElementStyle.overflow = "hidden"; // disable the potentials scrollbars
 
 var sinceBeginTime; // time since the begining
 var progressFactor; // coeficient that correspond to the advancement of the animation
 
 timer = setInterval(function() { // begin of the animation
  sinceBeginTime = new Date().getTime() - beginTime;
  if( sinceBeginTime < animationTime ) {
   progressFactor = sinceBeginTime / animationTime;
   AttrElementStyle.width=(Properties['width'] + DiffValues['width'] * progressFactor)  +"px";
   AttrElementStyle.height=(Properties['height'] + DiffValues['height'] * progressFactor) +"px";
   AttrElementStyle.padding=
    (Properties['padding']['top'] + DiffValues['padding']['top'] * progressFactor)  +"px "+
    (Properties['padding']['right'] + DiffValues['padding']['right'] * progressFactor) +"px "+
    (Properties['padding']['bot'] + DiffValues['padding']['bot'] * progressFactor)  +"px "+
    (Properties['padding']['left'] + DiffValues['padding']['left'] * progressFactor) +"px";
   AttrElementStyle.margin=
    (Properties['margin']['top'] + DiffValues['margin']['top'] * progressFactor)  +"px "+
    (Properties['margin']['right'] + DiffValues['margin']['right'] * progressFactor) +"px "+
    (Properties['margin']['bot'] + DiffValues['margin']['bot'] * progressFactor)  +"px "+
    (Properties['margin']['left'] + DiffValues['margin']['left'] * progressFactor)  +"px";
  }else {
   AttrElementStyle.width=options['width']  +"px";
   AttrElementStyle.height=options['height'] +"px";
   AttrElementStyle.padding=
    (Properties['padding']['top'] + DiffValues['padding']['top'])  +"px "+
    (Properties['padding']['right'] + DiffValues['padding']['right']) +"px "+
    (Properties['padding']['bot'] + DiffValues['padding']['bot'])  +"px "+
    (Properties['padding']['left'] + DiffValues['padding']['left'])  +"px";
   AttrElementStyle.margin=
    (Properties['margin']['top'] + DiffValues['margin']['top'])   +"px "+
    (Properties['margin']['right'] + DiffValues['margin']['right'])  +"px "+
    (Properties['margin']['bot'] + DiffValues['margin']['bot'])   +"px "+
    (Properties['margin']['left'] + DiffValues['margin']['left'])  +"px";
   clearInterval( timer ); // end of the animation
   if( callback!=null ) // if there is a CALLBACK then call it
    callback(Properties);
  }
 },15);
}
function slideUp( element, animationTime , callback) {
 morph( element, {
   height:0,
   padding:{
    top:0,
    bot:0
   },
   margin:{
    top:0,
    bot:0
   } },  animationTime, function(Properties) {
   // at the end of the slideUp we display: none the element and clean the other properties from style attribute
   var AttrElementStyle = element.style;
   AttrElementStyle.width="";
   AttrElementStyle.height="";
   AttrElementStyle.padding="";
   AttrElementStyle.margin="";
   element.style.display = 'none';
   if(callback)
    callback();
 });
}

function slideDown( element, animationTime , callback) {
 var AttrElementStyle = element.style;
 var ComputedElementStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element,null);
 
 AttrElementStyle.display="block";
 
 var options = { // the computed properties when element is displayed
 width:   parseInt( ComputedElementStyle.getPropertyValue("width")),
 height:  parseInt( ComputedElementStyle.getPropertyValue("height")),
 padding: {
  top:  parseInt(ComputedElementStyle.getPropertyValue("padding-top")),
  bot:  parseInt(ComputedElementStyle.getPropertyValue("padding-bottom"))
  },
 margin:{
  top:  parseInt(ComputedElementStyle.getPropertyValue("margin-top")),
  bot:  parseInt(ComputedElementStyle.getPropertyValue("margin-bottom"))
  } 
 };
 // after getting the actuals properties values of the element we flatten it
 AttrElementStyle.height="0";
 AttrElementStyle.paddingTop="0";
 AttrElementStyle.paddingBottom="0";
 AttrElementStyle.marginTop="0";
 AttrElementStyle.marginBottom="0";
 
 morph( element, options , animationTime, function() { // morph the element from flat to the options properties that are right
  // at the end of slideDown we clean up the style but keep the display: block if the element is display: none in the stylesheet
  AttrElementStyle.width="";
  AttrElementStyle.height="";
  AttrElementStyle.padding="";
  AttrElementStyle.margin="";
  element.style.display = 'block';
  if(callback) // if there is a CALLBACK then call it (we are in the morph() callback)
   callback();
 })
}
```

```css
p{
  width:50%;
  height:auto;
  padding:40px 0 10px;
  margin: 10px 0 40px;
  border:2px solid red
}
div{
  border:1px solid blue;
  padding:10px
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p id='p'>loiloilozoifboiygdouhbodihfgsd</br>rihgdggisbifghbsoifnsf</br>giodsbgsigfbsjgsgs</p>
</div>

<button onClick="slideUp( document.getElementById('p') ,500)">testUp</button>
<button onClick="slideDown( document.getElementById('p') ,500)">testDown</button>

<button id='btn1' onClick="morph( document.getElementById('btn1'),{ width: 120,height:130,padding:{top:70,left:50},margin:{right:40}} ,1000)">morphIt</button>
<button onClick="document.getElementById('btn1').style=''">reset btn1</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Make it shorter:**

```
<button onclick="slide()"></button>

<div id="box"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
slide(){document.getElementById("box").classList.toggle('hide');}

#box {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.hide {
  height: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on [Yami Odymels answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45654390/) here is a version that takes top- and bottom-padding into account, less relies on values set in css beforehand and also removes inline-styles after finishing the animation which prevents problems with viewport-resizes.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.the-wrap')
const button = document.querySelector('.the-button')

button.addEventListener('click', function() {

    // slide down
    if(!container.classList.contains('active')) {

        // show/remove display: none;
        container.classList.add('active')

        // get current height
        const height = container.clientHeight + "px"

        // remove height to 0
        container.style.height = 0;
        container.style.paddingTop = 0;
        container.style.paddingBottom = 0;
        container.style.overflow = "hidden";

        // this triggers applying the height and padding-values; does not show up on screen
        setTimeout(() => {

            // register removing properties after end of transition
            container.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
                container.style.height = "";
                container.style.transition = "";
                container.style.overflow = "";
            }, {once: true})

            // set transition
            container.style.transition = "height 0.5s ease, padding-top 0.5s ease, padding-bottom 0.5s ease";

            // set values to trigger transition
            container.style.height = height;
            container.style.paddingTop = "";
            container.style.paddingBottom = "";

        }, 0);

    }
    // slide up
    else {

        // explicitly set height, transitioning to auto-values is not included in spec
        container.style.height = container.clientHeight + "px";
        container.style.overflow = "hidden";
        container.style.transition = "height 0.5s ease, padding-top 0.5s ease, padding-bottom 0.5s ease";

        // again wait
        setTimeout(() => {

            // register cleanup
            container.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
                container.classList.remove('active')
                container.style.height = "";
                container.style.transition = "";
                container.style.overflow = "";
                container.style.paddingTop = "";
                container.style.paddingBottom = "";
            }, {once: true});

            // set to visually hidden, thus triggering transition
            container.style.height = 0;
            container.style.paddingTop = 0;
            container.style.paddingBottom = 0;

        }, 0);

    }

});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.the-wrap {
    outline: 2px solid crimson;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.the-wrap:not(.active) {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="the-button">toggle</button>

<div class="the-wrap">
    <h1>Headline</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Have a look at [the jQuery source for that effect](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js#L9) (`slideDown` calls `show`).

Comment: cowardly refusing to understand parts of jQuery (even though I've looked at the source many times) -->

Comment: I've looked at the source code for this but once entering Tween I've said to my self "I'm better off doing this by myself and learning in the process". Which I did => somewhere in here is my solution to this problem.