# JavaScript library to smoothly show/hide elements

Tags: javascript, css, show-hide

I need animate showing and hiding div element. Is there any JS library or CSS trick, that makes it possible? I know about jQuery and similar, but they're too big - I don't want use more than ~5 KB.

I also tried CSS transition, but it doesn't allow use display property. Visibility takes up place in page, what is undesirable.

---

**EDIT:**
For example:
[jQuery.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).
The second Demo from the top.

Comment: *"Visibility takes up place in page, what is undesirable."* As soon as you *start* fading it in, of course, you need that space... :-)

Comment: You could transition `height`

Comment: to precise, I want to smoothly change width and height of the div, for example from 0 to 500px. http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ <- Second Demo, you can see what I mean :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795481/javascript-slidedown-without-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS transitions. You don't need to touch the display property.

You can set the height/width (or both) of your div to 0, and then to your desired size, and activate the transition.

Or, you can fly in/fly out divs from your page if you animate their position (start from outside of the page and fly in to the desired position, and vice versa). You can slide them in from the top, or from left/right.

Answer (score 0):

This page seems to show the code needed to do this without jQuery:

http://brugbart.com/Articles/javascript-fade

Haven't read entirely through the page, though, so I can't say if it's legit or not.

Comment: But it's only fading the div - see my comment above :)