# Simple Navigation Menu needing slideout animation

Tags: javascript, navigation

I have a very simple navigation menu that opens onclick. However it simply pops into the screen and I would like it to "slide" down instead. I have very little JavaScript experience but I am trying to learn. I would really like to avoid JQuery if possible. Is there a way that I can simply add to the JavaScript that I have so I do not have to change the html and CSS a whole lot and it will slide? Thank you in advance for any help.

This is the code I am currently using:

**HTML:**

```
<table id="nav_menu">
<tr>
<td><a href="index.html" class="no_submenu">Home</a></td>
<td onmouseover="showmenu('about_us_menu')" onmouseout="hidemenu('about_us_menu')"><a class="with_submenu">About Us <img src="images/menu_down.png" /></a>
<table class="sub_menu" id="about_us_menu">
<tr><td><a href="about_us/link1.html">link1</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="about_us/link2.html">link2</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="about_us/link3.html">link3</a></td></tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
    table.sub_menu {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;}
```

**JAVASCIPT:**

```
    function showmenu(elmnt) {
    document.getElementById(elmnt).style.visibility="visible";
}

function hidemenu(elmnt) {
    document.getElementById(elmnt).style.visibility="hidden";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery slideDown function.

http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

```
function showmenu(elmnt) {
    $('#' + elmnt).slideDown("slow");
}

function hidemenu(elmnt) {
    $('#' + elmnt).slideUp("slow");
}
```

EDIT: Just noticed you would like to avoid jQuery, in that case see this previous question.
[JavaScript slidedown without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795481/javascript-slidedown-without-jquery)

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I cannot get this function to work with that I have. :-(