# How is it possible for jQuery to animate parts of websites?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

While I was browsing the web to learn more about jQuery and JavaScript I realized I have no idea how they work. Take for example the slideDown() method:

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("p").slideDown();
});
```

When a button is clicked it hides all p elements. How does the browser know what to do and how to do it when it reads this code?

jQuery is a library that is written in JavaScript. But does it do things that can also be done in JavaScript? Or did the creators of jQuery also talk with the people of web browsers to implement more functionality?

In a nutshell, my question is on a somewhat more fundamental level: how do browsers do what they do and how can code make them do it?

*/edit* The article "[How browsers work: Behind the scenes of modern web browsers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/)" shines some nice philosophical light on this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it all in Javascript. jQuery guys have no special deals with the browser authors.

In this case, it's achieved simply. First jQuery finds all the `<p>` elements and puts them in an array. On [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/queryselector) this is achieved with the `querySelector()` javascript method; on older ones I suspect that jQuery simply enumerates ALL elements and then picks the right ones.

After jQuery has all the elements in an array, it starts the "slideDown" effect. This is achieved simply by using Javascript timers (`setTimeout()` and `setInterval()`), plus manipulating CSS properties like `height` and such.

All in all, jQuery doesn't create anything new. Everything you can do with jQuery, you can do in plain old Javascript as well. Except that it would take a lot more writing.

Comment: Thanks, so jQuery does not create anything new. And the answer below that it is just CSS is not true. But how is the older functionality achieved? How does animation in browsers work under the hood?

Comment: @user2609980 - Huh? What do you mean? What is the "older functionality"? Anyways, browsers don't have a concept of "animation". They just render a static webpage (well, except for animated GIFs, I suppose). HTML and CSS specify what gets shown, but there is no animation there. Javascript is what adds the missing ingredient. It can change CSS properties and this forces the browser to redraw the page (or at least the affected part). If the CSS changes are done quickly enough by using timers (say, 10 times per second), it will seem like there is "animation".

Comment: @user2609980 a browser is just a desktop app like any other, except that it must implement open web standards.  If you really wanted to see how it works, you could check out open source implementations (like the V8 Javascript engine, written in C++).

Comment: @user2609980 - Say what? O_o How did we get from web browsers to video adapters?

Comment: @Vilx Ah nice I will look into Video Adapters.

Answer (score 2):

slideUp(), slideDown(), animate(), etc. are just changing some CSS properties very quickly over time. There's no additional functionality there. They just setInterval and change the height or position of the element a little bit each time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I understand that CSS is the language that does the animating. But the question remains: How does the browser know what to do and how to do it when it reads the CSS?

Comment: @user2609980 - CSS is in the browser's bloodstream. That along with HTML is at the heart of all modern webpages. And, yes - javascript can manipulate CSS and the browser will (more or less) instantly show the changes.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is a JavaScript library all functionality is achieved with JavaScript.

For example your `.slideDown()` method can be done like this:

```
function slideDown (element, duration, finalheight, callback) {
    var s = element.style;
    s.height = '0px';

    var y = 0;
    var framerate = 10;
    var one_second = 1000;
    var interval = one_second*duration/framerate;
    var totalframes = one_second*duration/interval;
    var heightincrement = finalheight/totalframes;
    var tween = function () {
        y += heightincrement;
        s.height = y+'px';
        if (y<finalheight) {
            setTimeout(tween,interval);
        }
    }
    tween();
}
```

Source: [JavaScript slidedown without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795481/javascript-slidedown-without-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell: Each browser vendor implements functionality (for the DOM, javascript, CSS, etc.) and exposes it through (nowadays) standardized APIs in Javascript/CSS/HTML.

Your question on how jQuery does it's thing can be answered easily by looking at the [jQuery source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery).

Comment: Thanks I have taken a look and it is indeed just JavaScript. But the question was meant on a bit deeper level. How can the API's do what they do?

Comment: @user2609980 Well, because it's implemented by the browser vendor. If they expose an API for e.g. a new CSS property `foo` that inverts your page-colors, then that logic is implemented by them and exposed through the CSS property.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does do things that can be done in javascript.

You can get the code if you want from jquery to investigate how it does specific things.

Slide up and slide down are helpers for jquery animate. JQuery animate can modify any css property width height opacity etc. SlideDown/up just modifies Top css property.

Must admit I've never troubled myself to figure out how it's done, I'm pretty sure it's using setInterval feature to modify the property at intervals.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/