# Convert Jquery slidetoggle code to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I convert the jQuery slidetoggle() function into Javascript?

```
 var $context = getContext(context);

        $($context).on('click', '.m_menu', function () {
            $('.w_nav').slideToggle();
        });
```

Comment: the good news is that jQuery is javascript, so you could just check the jQuery source code, that would help

Comment: The subject has already been treated here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795481/javascript-slidedown-without-jquery

Enjoy.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well this is not converting the jQuery code to javascript, but rather doing it in plain javascript. It can be achieved in different ways. Here are two that comes to my mind:

**HTML:**

```
<button id="mbtn" onclick="slideToggle()">SlideToggle</button>
<div id="mdiv">Some context</div>
```

**1. Using javascript's `setInterval` :**
Having a boolean value to keep track of whether we need to slideUp or slideDown (toggle) and using `setInterval` to increase/decrease the height.

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/mktrywLr/)

**Javascript:**

```
var slideOpen = true;
var heightChecked = false;
var initHeight = 0;
var intval = null;

function slideToggle() {
    window.clearInterval(intval);
    var mdiv = document.getElementById('mdiv');
    if(!heightChecked) {
        initHeight = mdiv.offsetHeight;
        heightChecked = true;
    }
    if(slideOpen) {
        var h = initHeight;
        slideOpen = false;
        intval = setInterval(function(){
            h--;
            mdiv.style.height = h + 'px';
            if(h <= 0)
                window.clearInterval(intval);
            }, 1
        );
    }
    else {
        var h = 0;
        slideOpen = true;
        intval = setInterval(function(){
            h++;
            mdiv.style.height = h + 'px';
            if(h >= initHeight)
                window.clearInterval(intval);
            }, 1
        );
    }
}
```

**2. Using [CSS3 transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions):**
Getting help from CSS3 transition to go along with javascript which will make it a lot easier to achieve the slide effect. Then we'll only need to change the height in javascript and the rest is done.

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/rswgb29a/)

**CSS:**

```
#mdiv {
    /* other styles */
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
var slideOpen = true;
var heightChecked = false;
var initHeight = 0;

function slideToggle() {
    var mdiv = document.getElementById('mdiv');
    if(!heightChecked) {
        initHeight = mdiv.offsetHeight;
        heightChecked = true;
    }
    if(slideOpen) {
        slideOpen = false;
        mdiv.style.height = '0px';
    }
    else {
        slideOpen = true;
        mdiv.style.height = initHeight + 'px';
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
If we want the starting height to be 0, then we'll need a few changes:

```
var slideOpen = false;
//var heightChecked = false;
var initHeight = 120; //height of the element when it's fully open
```

And we need to comment this bit out:

```
/*
if(!heightChecked) {
    initHeight = mdiv.offsetHeight;
    heightChecked = true;
}
*/
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/hgspv8f5/)

**EDIT #2**
As Sandro pointed out, context wasn't actually getting hidden so updated the fiddles and added `overflow-y: hidden;` and changed the text color for visibility.
Also changed open to slideOpen since open is sort of a reserved word.

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to accomplish.  Thanks for this!

Comment: How can this be accomplished when the starting height is 0,   and increased when button is clicked?

Comment: Can't check arm, but you'll probably need 2 changes. First change initial value for open to false and give initHeigh the actual height and remove the first initHeight. Will check in a few hours when I'm behind a computer.

Comment: No worries, I think I figured it out.

Comment: Glad that you figured it out. Added it to the answer just in case it helps someone.

Comment: this works well, but I have a question.  What if the height is not a fixed variable.  Would I be able to set the height to 'auto'?

Comment: Having no height how? It expands till it fills its parent? expands till we press sildeToggle again? Or?

Comment: Sorry let me rephrase.  This is for a navigation.  Depending on what item was selected the box would resize itself to partcular menu.  There is a height, but it's not fixed.

Comment: So as I understand the slider will be a container for the selected item, and the items have different height? If yes, then we just need to get the height of the selected item and assign it to initHeight (or pass it to the function).

Comment: The content `some context` is not really hidden after the box slided to be closed. It's color just matches the background color but it's still there. In cases where the text of the box that should be closed has the same color as the surrounding background this should not work I guess. But the answer from chebaby does.

Comment: @Sandro You're right, adding `overflow-y: hidden;` (or overflow: hidden;) to the sliding element will fix the issue. Updated the answer and fiddles. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

To reimplement (convert) jquery **slideToggle()** to vanilla javascript, you need to reimplement jquery **slideUp()** and **slideDown()** as well.

```js
var DOMAnimations = {
    
    /**
    * SlideUp
    *
    * @param {HTMLElement} element
    * @param {Number} duration
    * @returns {Promise<boolean>}
    */
    slideUp: function (element, duration = 500) {

        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

            element.style.height = element.offsetHeight + 'px';
            element.style.transitionProperty = `height, margin, padding`;
            element.style.transitionDuration = duration + 'ms';
            element.offsetHeight;
            element.style.overflow = 'hidden';
            element.style.height = 0;
            element.style.paddingTop = 0;
            element.style.paddingBottom = 0;
            element.style.marginTop = 0;
            element.style.marginBottom = 0;
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                element.style.display = 'none';
                element.style.removeProperty('height');
                element.style.removeProperty('padding-top');
                element.style.removeProperty('padding-bottom');
                element.style.removeProperty('margin-top');
                element.style.removeProperty('margin-bottom');
                element.style.removeProperty('overflow');
                element.style.removeProperty('transition-duration');
                element.style.removeProperty('transition-property');
                resolve(false);
            }, duration)
        })
    },

    /**
    * SlideDown
    *
    * @param {HTMLElement} element
    * @param {Number} duration
    * @returns {Promise<boolean>}
    */
    slideDown: function (element, duration = 500) {

        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

            element.style.removeProperty('display');
            let display = window.getComputedStyle(element).display;

            if (display === 'none') 
                display = 'block';

            element.style.display = display;
            let height = element.offsetHeight;
            element.style.overflow = 'hidden';
            element.style.height = 0;
            element.style.paddingTop = 0;
            element.style.paddingBottom = 0;
            element.style.marginTop = 0;
            element.style.marginBottom = 0;
            element.offsetHeight;
            element.style.transitionProperty = `height, margin, padding`;
            element.style.transitionDuration = duration + 'ms';
            element.style.height = height + 'px';
            element.style.removeProperty('padding-top');
            element.style.removeProperty('padding-bottom');
            element.style.removeProperty('margin-top');
            element.style.removeProperty('margin-bottom');
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                element.style.removeProperty('height');
                element.style.removeProperty('overflow');
                element.style.removeProperty('transition-duration');
                element.style.removeProperty('transition-property');
            }, duration)
        })
    },

    /**
    * SlideToggle
    *
    * @param {HTMLElement} element
    * @param {Number} duration
    * @returns {Promise<boolean>}
    */
    slideToggle: function (element, duration = 500) {

        if (window.getComputedStyle(element).display === 'none') {

            return this.slideDown(element, duration);

        } else {

            return this.slideUp(element, duration);
        }
    }
}

// ------------------------------------------------------

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    var button = document.getElementById('slideToggle');

    var cardElement = document.getElementById('firstCard');

    button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        DOMAnimations.slideToggle(cardElement);
    });

});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Add a gray background color with some padding */
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Header/Blog Title */
.header {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
}

/* Create two unequal columns that floats next to each other */
/* Left column */
.leftcolumn {   
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Fake image */
.fakeimg {
    background-color: #aaa;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}

/* Add a card effect for articles */
.card {
    position:relative;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#slideToggle {
    background-color: #f9f5f5;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #a9b5a9;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top:20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

/* Footer */
.footer {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ddd;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 800px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .leftcolumn, .rightcolumn {   
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
    <h2>Blog Name</h2>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="leftcolumn">
        <button id="slideToggle">slideToggle</button>
        <div class="card" id="firstCard">
            <h2>FIRST TITLE HEADING</h2>
            <h5>Title description, Dec 7, 2018</h5>
            <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
            <p>Some text..</p>
            <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <h2>SECOND TITLE HEADING</h2>
            <h5>Title description, Dec 7, 2018</h5>
            <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
            <p>Some text..</p>
            <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
    <h2>Footer</h2>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this answer is "more correct" since OP states "Convert Jquery slidetoggle code to Javascript". And sorry for being a little late to the party...

Answer (score 1):

I am giving a lightweight answer. You can think of it as a skeleton example, and you can play with it, style it later, according to your preferences.

> Before you begin, I would like to clarify that I'm not converting `jQuery` `slideToggle()` function into one in `JavaScript`

**All I'm doing is, trying to replicate that function in the simplest possible form!**

## Step 1:

Create a button/(any other element), which you can link with an `eventListener`.

## Step 2:

Create an element, which you want to toggle/slide/whatever you want to call it!

## Step 3:

Go ahead with your `javaScript`, and create a **conditional** `setInterval()` for a function linked with that `eventListener`.

> You can give your suggestions in the comment section.

```js
var animxB = 0;
var anim2B = 0;
document.getElementById("animB").addEventListener("click", performB);

function performB() {
anim2B++;
anim3B = anim2B % 2;
var fram1B = setInterval(framB, 1);

function framB() {
    if (anim3B == 1) {
        animxB++;
        document.getElementById("divB").style.width = animxB + "px";
        document.getElementById("divB").style.height = animxB + "px";
        if (animxB >= 200) {
            clearInterval(fram1B);
            document.getElementById("animB").innerHTML = "Click(-)";
        }
    }
    if (anim3B == 0) {
        animxB--;
        document.getElementById("divB").style.width = animxB + "px";
        document.getElementById("divB").style.height = animxB + "px";
        if (animxB <= 0) {
            clearInterval(fram1B);
            document.getElementById("animB").innerHTML = "Click(+)";
        }
    }


}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
<button id="animB" style="font-weight:bold; color:brown;">Click(+)</button>
<div id="divB" style="width:0; height:0; overflow:auto; color:gray; font-family:sans-serif; font-size:13px;">
    &lt;path d="M10 10 v80 h80 v-80 h-80" fill="gray" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" /&gt; &lt;path d="M40 10 v20" stroke="blue" stroke-width="0.5" /&gt; &lt;path d="M10 30 h30" stroke="red" stroke-width="0.5" /&gt; &lt;circle cx="40" cy="30" r="2" fill="purple" stroke="purple" stroke-width="1" /&gt;
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution more simple in vanilla i leave it here
html->

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" />
    <script src="js.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="dropdown">Menu</div>
      <div class="menu_main">
        <div class="menu__item">Item 1</div>
        <div class="menu__item">Item 2</div>
        <div class="menu__item">Item 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      text behind of menu
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.menu {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.dropdown {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 30px 10px lime;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 7px 35px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 900;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.menu_main {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0%; /* 300 */
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 1250ms;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2);
}

.menu__item {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 34%;
  background-color: rgb(189, 243, 201);
}
```

JS

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const boton = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown")[0];

  boton.addEventListener(
    "click",
    function (e) {
      if (
        window
          .getComputedStyle(e.target.nextElementSibling, null)
          .getPropertyValue("height") == "0px"
      ) {
        e.target.nextElementSibling.style.height = "300%";
      } else {
        e.target.nextElementSibling.style.height = "0%";
      }
    },
    false
  );
});
```

this code does not have slideUp and SlideDown, it has all together. to use it once

Comment: can you please add the demo

Answer (score 0):

```
You Just need Vanilla Js to accomplish what you need, by the way Here is the laziest way

//i  hope this will solve your issue
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=0.1,shrink-to-fit=no">
     <link type="text/css" href="/css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <title>slideToggle</title>
        <style>
.toggle-navigation{
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out !important;
  margin:100px auto;
}
.toggle-content{
transition: all .3s ease-in-out !important;
}
 </style>
</head>
   <body>
    <div class="toggle navigation bg-primary w-25" id="toggle-nav" onclick = "toggleNavigation();">
     <p class="text-white text-center font-weight-bold">Click To Expand</p>
      <div class="toggle-content" id="toggle-content">
       <p class="text-white font-weight-bold text-justify">
Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet , Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet , Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet , Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet , Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet , Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
         </p>
        </div>
       </div>
<script>
let toggleNav = document.getElementById('toggle-nav');
    navHeight = toggleNav.offsetHeight;
    content= document.getElementById('toggle-content');
    contentHeight = content.offsetTop - content.offsetTop;
    content.style.height = contentHeight;

    toggle = true ;
    function toggleNavigation(){
    if(toggle){
    content.style.height = navHeight;
    }else{
    content.style.height = contentHeight;
    }
    toggle = !toggle;
}
    </script>
   </body>
  </html>
```