# jquery toggle slide animation to pure javascript animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

See here
https://jsfiddle.net/97Lahmoh/ OR http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FB8TE2KSHGZ5

basically I want to use jquery ui toggle slide animation without any jquery and plugins.
this is jquery code which does the work.

```
$( "#effect" ).toggle("slide", {direction: "left"}, 500);
```

how to use it on pure javascript code? I'm not good at animations.

Comment: why you convert to javascript any reason behind on this question?

Comment: `I want to use jquery ui toggle slide animation without any jquery and plugins` you can't use jquery without jquery

Comment: `Can anyone convert it to pure javascript animation?` - yes, you'd have to ask a programmer to do it for you - don't ask on SO for a programmer to do it for you

Comment: what I want is pure javascript animation without jquery. It's mean I want (toggle slide animation) in pure javascript code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Jquery slidetoggle code to Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29949331/convert-jquery-slidetoggle-code-to-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css transition with position property.

try this one:

```js
function toggle() {
  var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
  if (document.getElementsByClassName("hide").length == 0) {
    div1.className = "test hide";
  } else {
    div1.className = "test show";
  }

}
```

```css
.test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #2354A4;
  transition: left 2s;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

.hide {
  left: -250px;
}

.show {
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="test hide">

</div>

<button id="btnToggle" onclick="toggle()" type="button" name="btnToggle">TOGGLE</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achive this by using `css` `transition` property.

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/97Lahmoh/5/)

Comment: function runEffect() {
    var el = document.getElementById("effect");
    if (el.classList) {
        el.classList.toggle("slideDiv");
    } else {
        var classes = el.className.split(' ');
        var existingIndex = classes.indexOf("slideDiv");

        if (existingIndex >= 0)
            classes.splice(existingIndex, 1);
        else
            classes.push("slideDiv");

        el.className = classes.join(' ');
    }

}

Comment: instead of toggle class I'll use it pure javascript. then it'll work. thanx for the css. https://jsfiddle.net/97Lahmoh/6/