# Vue Transition - JavaScript hooks

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52137259/2953308), I'm trying to create a Vue `slideToggle` component using transition.

The slideToggle is a classic paradigm in height animation. I've been successful so far...

I don't want to set a fixed `max-height` or `height`, I want the `height` to be dynamic.

My animation is working properly when displaying and hiding. The problem is in canceling while displaying or hiding.

How to handle the `@enter-cancelled` and the `@leave-cancelled` hooks? I'm new to vue transitions :)

I put my code inside this CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-3b7oj

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this helps you, but try this:

declare a new variable:

```
data() {
  return {
    height: null,
    toggling: false
  };
},
```

when the open or close function start, verify if `toggling` is true, if yes, just cancel, like this:

```
    enter(el) {
      if (this.toggling) return;
      this.toggling = true;
      this.height = el.offsetHeight;

      el.style.overflow = "hidden";
      el.style.height = 0;
      el.style.paddingTop = 0;
      el.style.paddingBottom = 0;
      el.style.marginTop = 0;
      el.style.marginBottom = 0;

      setTimeout(() => {
        el.style.transitionProperty = `height, margin, padding`;
        el.style.transitionDuration = this.duration + "ms";
        el.style.height = this.height + "px";
        el.style.removeProperty("padding-top");
        el.style.removeProperty("padding-bottom");
        el.style.removeProperty("margin-top");
        el.style.removeProperty("margin-bottom");
        this.toggling = false;
      });
    },
```

Will be something like this:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-78n7t?fontsize=14

Maybe i broke your code, sorry, but will you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

As per the offical documentation [Javacript transition hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#JavaScript-Hooks)
the @leave-cancelled is only available with v-show, where are in your sample code you are using v-if, if you change this you will be able to capture the @leave-cancelled hook,@leave-cancelled and @enter-cancelled are triggered when enter or leave are interrupted, say you press the toggle button while opening as well as pressing the button while its closing.

Answer (score 0):

## Vue-Transition-Cancel

***tl;dr***

---

- leave event cancels not yet called enter
- enter cancels not yet called leave

cancel state is stored in

- `el._enterCb.cancelled`
- `el._leaveCb.cancelled`

---

***analysis***

---

### Consider:

```
const cb = el._enterCb = once(() => {
    if (expectsCSS) {
      removeTransitionClass(el, toClass)
      removeTransitionClass(el, activeClass)
    }
    if (cb.cancelled) {
      if (expectsCSS) {
        removeTransitionClass(el, startClass)
      }
      enterCancelledHook && enterCancelledHook(el)
    } else {
      afterEnterHook && afterEnterHook(el)
    }
    el._enterCb = null
  })
```

> source: [_enterCb](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/8a2dbf50105ea729125a42fecfe2c2f0371d7836/src/platforms/web/runtime/modules/transition.js#L115)

### So a naive solution to cancel `@enter` is

`el => {el._enterCb.cancelled = true; done()}`

---

#### This is what actually happens when one triggers `leave`

```
// call enter callback now
  if (isDef(el._enterCb)) {
    el._enterCb.cancelled = true
    el._enterCb()
  }
```

> source: [leave](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/8a2dbf50105ea729125a42fecfe2c2f0371d7836/src/platforms/web/runtime/modules/transition.js#L180)

---

### Same applies to:

```
  const cb = el._leaveCb = once(() => {
    if (el.parentNode && el.parentNode._pending) {
      el.parentNode._pending[vnode.key] = null
    }
    if (expectsCSS) {
      removeTransitionClass(el, leaveToClass)
      removeTransitionClass(el, leaveActiveClass)
    }
    if (cb.cancelled) {
      if (expectsCSS) {
        removeTransitionClass(el, leaveClass)
      }
      leaveCancelled && leaveCancelled(el)
    } else {
      rm()
      afterLeave && afterLeave(el)
    }
    el._leaveCb = null
  })
```

> source: [_leaveCb](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/8a2dbf50105ea729125a42fecfe2c2f0371d7836/src/platforms/web/runtime/modules/transition.js#L222)

---

***One can check for possible assignments:***

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/search?q=_leaveCb&unscoped_q=_leaveCb