# How to change jquery to js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert following jquery to javascript any one help?
thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button.navbar-toggle').click(function () {
      $('div#navbar-collapse').slideToggle("slow");
      return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: Have you tried yourself? if so please show us.

Comment: Please check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29949331/convert-jquery-slidetoggle-code-to-javascript/29950973

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps to do:

- At first you could use the **[Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)** instead of jQuerys selectors.
- After that you have to write your own 'slideToggle' function, because its a function of jQuery.

  > This could be done for example by manipulating the styles or writing CSS classes and add or remove them using `yourElement.classList.add()/.remove()`

Answer (score 0):

My approach using css transition and vanilla javascript:

```js
document.querySelector("button.navbar-toggle").addEventListener("click", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.querySelector("#navbar-collapse").classList.toggle("animate");
})
```

```css
#navbar-collapse{
  background: gold;
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  position:absolute;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  margin-left: 0;
}
#navbar-collapse.animate{
  margin-left: -150px;
}
```

```html
<button class="navbar-toggle">nav toggle</button>
<div id="navbar-collapse">
  test navbar
</div>
```