# Javascript native implementation div display/hide with animate

Tags: javascript, html, css, display

I am looking for a  native JS solution to toggle div display using display:'none' and display:'block' properties. I have the first part done. I only need the part to do a simple fadeIn and fadeOut animation.

I need to use native JS and display:block,none.

```
var e = document.getElementById('calendarPickerContainer');

    if (e.className == 'visible') { 
        e.className = 'hidden';
    } else {
        e.className = 'visible';
    }
```

need to adapt to this css

```
.visible{
display:block;
}

.hidden {
display:none;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795481/javascript-slidedown-without-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanna use a pure JavaScript `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`, try this:

```
transition: opacity 1s linear;
```

This is a pure CSS method.

```css
#cont {-webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear; -o-transition: opacity 1s linear; transition: opacity 1s linear;}
#cont.hidden {opacity: 0;}
```

```html
<button onclick="cont.classList.add('hidden'); setTimeout('cont.style.display=\'none\'', 1000);">Click</button>
<div id="cont">
  Hello
</div>
```

**Working Snippet** (includes toggle):

```css
#cont {-webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear; -o-transition: opacity 1s linear; transition: opacity 1s linear; opacity: 1;}
#cont.hidden {opacity: 0; -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear; -o-transition: opacity 1s linear; transition: opacity 1s linear;}
```

```html
<button onclick="if (cont.style.display != 'none') { cont.classList.add('hidden'); setTimeout('cont.style.display=\'none\'', 1000); } else {cont.style.display='block'; setTimeout('cont.classList.remove(\'hidden\')', 10);}">Click</button>
<div id="cont">
  Hello
</div>
```

Comment: need to use display block and none

Comment: @Jacob I have used `display: none`. Did you see the code?

Comment: Only fadesOut doesn't fadeIn

Comment: I also get an error that cont is undefined by the timeout function

Comment: @Jacob Sorry my mistake. Updated. Check the second fiddle now.

Comment: @Jacob I couldn't find any error, moreover, did you check the second snippet?

Comment: Yes the error is a little delayed so there must be something with the timeout function

Comment: @Jacob I couldn't find even a single error, after a few seconds or even minutes. Did you refresh the page and check?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this easily with CSS3

```
.visible {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 2s linear;
}
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s linear;
}
```

Comment: No animation is visible.

Answer (score 0):

Native JS fade function:

```
var s = document.getElementById('calendarPickerContainer').style;
s.opacity = 1;
(function fade(){(s.opacity-=.1)<0?s.display="none":setTimeout(fade,40)})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplfy this with `classList`

```
document.querySelector('.toggle').addEventListener('click',function(e) {
  e.target.classList.toggle('hide');
})
```

Css:

```
div {
  transition:all 0.3s ease-in;
}

.hide {

  opacity: 0;
}
```

We're using `opacity` since `display` cannot be animated.

[**Example**](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/jbjQwy)