# how to add delay to hide / show div with pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I was using jquery script like below for hiding and showing a div with a delay in milliseconds:

```
function slideonlyone(thechosenone) {
 $('.newboxes2').each(function(index) {
      if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
           $(this).slideDown(200);
      }
      else {
           $(this).slideUp(600);
      }
 });
}
```

How can i achieve this result in pure javascript? This is the code i have at the moment:

```
 function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
  var newboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
        for(var x=0; x<newboxes.length; x++) {
              name = newboxes[x].getAttribute("class");
              if (name == 'newboxes') {
                    if (newboxes[x].id == thechosenone) {
                    newboxes[x].style.display = 'block';
              }
              else {
                    newboxes[x].style.display = 'none';
              }
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: setTimeout(function(){ // your JS }, 200);

Comment: but in your case, setInterval(), and then element hidden, clearInterval().

Comment: can you tell me where i have to put these lines of code?

Comment: Just to be clear, you don't want to slide the elements, you just want to wait a little bit, and then show them? Recreating jQuery's slide functions is not something that is done with a few lines of javascript ?

Comment: yes actually i want the slide in millliseconds like in jquery

Comment: Then you'd have to either create your own functions for animations, use a different library for animations, like GSAP etc. or just use CSS3 instead.

Comment: There are some examples here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795481/javascript-slidedown-without-jquery

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery `slideDown` effect is not as simple in plain Javascript, but you can set any CSS property with ease.

`display: none` will make it appear as if box does not exist, and its width and height will be equal to 0. If you want there to be a blank space where the box is, you can use `visibility: hidden` or `opacity: 0`. If you use the latter and add the CSS `transition: opacity .2s ease` to the element, you can make it fade in.

```
function showOnlyOne(theChosenOne) {
  var newBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('div.newboxes');
  for (var i = 0, len = newBoxes.length; i < len; ++i) {
    var box = newBoxes[i];
    if (box.id === theChosenOne) {
      box.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      box.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks. I see i can achieve the same effect with css only using transitions. I will give that a try.