# Accessibly hide and show content after animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility, hidden

I'm implementing a component that has some hidden content, revealed on a button click. I'd like to run a transition on the `max-height` of the revealed content, like so:

```html
<button id="show-hide">Toggle content</button>
<div id="revealable-content" class="content is-collapsed">
Content to be revealed
  <a href="https://www.example.com">with a link</a>
</div>
```

```css
.content {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: darkgray;
  transition: max-height 1000ms;
}

.content.is-collapsed {
  max-height: 0
}
```

```js
const button = document.getElementById('show-hide')
const content = document.getElementById('revealable-content')
let hidden = true

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  hidden = !hidden

  if (hidden) {
    content.classList.add('is-collapsed')  
  } else {
    content.classList.remove('is-collapsed')
  }
})
```

So far so good. Now I want to make this more accessible, so I add a `hidden` attribute to the content div, and set this to true or false after I know the animation has executed using `setTimeout`:

```js
// at the bottom of the event handler...
setTimeout(() => {
  content.hidden = hidden
}, 1000)
```

This breaks the "expanding" animation, but curiously not the "collapsing" animation. On collapse, the transition animation runs for 1 second as expected. However on expand, the `max-height` is applied immediately with no transition.

See [this codepen](https://codepen.io/SiAdcock/pen/RwWaJGQ) for a demo.

What's going on, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is your issue solved by now? Any updates here?

Comment: @noChance Thanks for checking back! I found a solution that I was could live with, but it came at the expense of having no animation on collapse. I decided that using `setTimeout` was too brittle and had weird behaviour if the user closed or opened the accordion before the animation had completed.

Comment: Timeouts belong to animations like wheels to a car. You don't go an unusual way by keeping them.

Comment: @noChance I kinda disagree with you there. We should try to use animation tools provided by the platform like `requestAnimationFrame`, CSS keyframes and transitions as much as possible. Timeouts really should be a last resort, and in my case, produced a worse experience than having no animation at all. In case you're interested, my work in progress is here: https://guardian.github.io/source/?path=/story/accordion--default-grey

Comment: Agreed, `requestAnimationFrame` is the way to go. However, CSS keyframes and transitions are very much limited to a few use cases. More complex animations are most of the time depending on timeouts somehow. Anyway, IMO your work looks just fine, the way you finally did it - I actually like the snappy collapse.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**
The solution seems to be much easier than expected. Using a short timeout of, e.g 10ms before removing the `is-collapsed`-class will do the trick for you:

Note: I set the timeout to 100ms, since using firefox the transition is not always as smooth as in chrome.

```js
const button = document.getElementById('show-hide');
const content = document.getElementById('revealable-content');
let hidden = true;

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    hidden = !hidden;
  
  if (hidden) {
    content.classList.add('is-collapsed');
    return setTimeout(() => {
      content.hidden = hidden;
    }, 1000);
  }

  content.hidden = hidden;
  return setTimeout(() => {
    content.classList.remove('is-collapsed');
  }, 100);
})
```

```css
.content {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: darkgray;
  transition: max-height 1000ms linear;
}

.content.is-collapsed {
  max-height: 0
}
```

```html
<button id="show-hide">Toggle content</button>
<div hidden id="revealable-content" class="content is-collapsed">
Content to be revealed
  <a href="https://www.example.com">with a link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the element with `hidden` attribute have browser porpertis like this:

```
div[Attributes Style] {
display: none;
}
```

`display: none;` is damaging the animation.

This could be a solution, works for me:

**UPDATED**

```js
const button = document.getElementById('show-hide')
const content = document.getElementById('revealable-content')
let hidden = true

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  hidden = !hidden
  
  
  if (hidden) {    
    content.classList.add('is-collapsed')    
  } else {
    content.style.display = 'block'; // set display block before class is-collapsed removes
    setTimeout(() => {
      content.classList.remove('is-collapsed')
      content.style.display = ''; // clear css display  
    }, 100); //changed time interval for Firefox 
    
  }
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    content.hidden = hidden
  }, 1000)
})
```

```css
.content {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: darkgray;
  transition: max-height 1000ms;
  display: block; 
}

.content.is-collapsed {
  max-height: 0;
}

/*added to hide collapsed element*/
.content.is-collapsed[hidden] {
  display: none; 
}
```

```html
<button id="show-hide">Toggle content</button>
<div hidden id="revealable-content" class="content is-collapsed">
Content to be revealed
  <a href="https://www.example.com">with a link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This does preserve the animation, but the collapsed content is no longer hidden to screen reader users or keyboard users. For example, you can still tab to the link in the `content` element, even when it is collpased.

Comment: Thanks! It mostly works, but the expand animation is lost in Firefox for some reason.

Comment: Changed time setTimeout form 1ms to 100. Now it works in Firefox

Answer (score 0):

`height: auto;` has no animation effect but the height property. But when your element is hidden `(display: none)` you can not get the height. So you need to clone it and get the height then you can apply animation using the height.

Full credit goes to this [[Q-A]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795481/javascript-slidedown-without-jquery)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Avinash</title>

<style>
  #slider {
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:0px;
    width:400px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    background:#0f0;   
  height:20px;
  overflow:hidden;
  }
</style>
<script>
  
var minheight = 20;
var maxheight = 300;
var time = 1000;
var timer = null;
var toggled = false;

window.onload = function() {
  var controler = document.getElementById('slide');
  var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
  slider.style.height = minheight + 'px';
  controler.onclick = function() {  
    clearInterval(timer);
    var instanceheight = parseInt(slider.style.height);
    var init = (new Date()).getTime();
    var height = (toggled = !toggled) ? maxheight: minheight; 
    
    var disp = height - parseInt(slider.style.height);
    timer = setInterval(function() {
      var instance = (new Date()).getTime() - init;
      if(instance < time ) {
        var pos = Math.floor(disp * instance / time);
        result = instanceheight + pos;
        slider.style.height =  result + 'px';
        document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = 'Current Height : <b>' + result + '</b><br /> Current Time : <b>' + instance + '</b>';
      }else {
        slider.style.height = height + 'px'; //safety side ^^
        clearInterval(timer);
        controler.value = toggled ? ' Slide Up ' :' Slide Down ';
        document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = 'Current Height : <b>' + height + '</b><br /> Current Time : <b>' + time + '</b>';
      }
    },1);
  };
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Toggle Slide </h1>
  <input type="button" id="slide" value =" Slide Down "/>
  <span id="log" style="position:absolute; left:10px; top:150px;"></span>
  <br />
  <div id="slider">
     content goes here
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Muhammad. I was hoping I wouldn't have to dynamically calculate the height of the content, but it might be the only way. I'll see if anyone else comes up with anything.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in js logic. When content is hidden, and you press the button to show it, animation is applied while content is still hidden, and after animation is finished, you remove hidden attribute, which shows content immediately.

Just change your click handler code to:

```
if(hidden){
  content.hidden = false
}else {
  setTimeout(() => {
    content.hidden = true
  }, 1000)
}

hidden = !hidden


setTimeout(() => {
   if (hidden) {
    content.classList.add('is-collapsed')  
   } else {
    content.classList.remove('is-collapsed')
  }
})
```

Second timoeout is required because of the reason stated in Muhammad Tahazzot answer - height is not known until element is not hidden. setTimeout without delay executes code in next task - when element is not hidden, so height can be obtained.

And why do you need hidden attribute at all? If you want to hide content from screen readers, use aria-hidden="true", if you want content to be not focusable with tab, use tabindex="-1"

Comment: Thanks! It mostly works, but the expand animation is lost in Firefox for some reason